# Why is textFieldDidEndEditing: not being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfielddelegate

I've got a UITextField, and when text gets entered into that, I want to obtain the doubleValue from the text field and perform some computations and display them in a UITableView.

The delegate for the UITextField adopts the UITextFieldDelegate protocol, and implements both textFieldShouldReturn: and textFieldDidEndEditing: methods.  textFieldShouldReturn: resigns first responder status which, according to docs should also trigger textFieldDidEndEditing:, but I never see textFieldDidEndEditing: called.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == thresholdValue) {
        [thresholdValue resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self updateThresholdValue:textField];
}
```

It may be worth noting that I also tried connecting some of the textfield events to the delegate and having the event call updateThresholdValue: directly, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Put some NSLogs to make sure the method is never actually being called.

Comment: You did myTextField.delegate = self somewhere right?

Comment: I assume he has his delegate wired correctly otherwise textFieldShouldReturn: wouldn't be being called either.

Comment: But I concur with your first comment - have you tried NSLog or setting a breakpoint to confirm the delegate isn't being called? Could it be that it is being called but `[self updateThresholdValue:textField];` isn't doing what you expect it to?

Comment: I have not used NSLog(); I've set a breakpoint in my implementation of textFieldDidEndEditing: and it's not triggered.  A similar breakpoint in textFieldShouldReturn: does trigger.

Comment: Regarding field.delegate = self...no, I have not done that.  The delegate is the subclass of the UIViewController that controls the view in which the textfield resides.  I would swear that I read last night that UITextFields cannot be their own delegate.

Wait...I see what you're saying.  You're wondering if I wired textfield's delegate up.  Yes.  That's done in IB and, as Luke indicated, the fact that textFieldShouldReturn: is being called seems to indicate that the delegate is properly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, I tried replicating a simpler version of what I was trying to do using a HelloWorld app, and it worked on the first try, with no problems, just as expected.  Faced with that, I began to wonder a bit.

Somewhere in all the googling I did to try to get an answer to this problem, I ran across a link where a person was having a problem with events not firing from a button, and it turned out that the problem was related to the view in which the button was placed and that view having another subview as a peer to the button, and that subview was somehow eating the events rather than allowing them to go where they'd been directed.  The scenario wasn't exactly the same as mine, but it sounded close enough that investigation would be worthwhile.  Despite all the excellent advice received here, none had yet borne fruit.

Last night I decided to completely re-create the nib file from scratch (made a copy of what I had first), and I got it to work.  The key difference seems to be that I in the original non-working nib file, I had dragged over a `TableViewController` from the palette, then changed its type to my subclass `PZTableViewController`.  When I did that same thing in my new nib, the events didn't fire.  If, on the other hand, I removed the dragged-over `TableViewController` and instead just dragged over an `NSObject` and changed its class to `PZTableViewController` and plumbed everything up, it all "just worked".

I will try to chase down the link that got me started on this line of thinking and post it either as an edit or as a comment.

This is also not a complete answer because I do not yet understand the difference between the from-the-palette `TableViewController` and my subclass.  When I figure that out, I will update this answer via edit or comment.

Answer (score 9):

Just ran into the same problem you described. After trying everything I could think of I added this delegate method:

```
// if we encounter a newline character return
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{   
    // enter closes the keyboard
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now the textFieldShouldEndEditing fires and the text field resigns first responder.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: now consider the case when you have two UITextFields on the same VC. Is it a good idea to resign kbd on enter?

Answer (score 7):

textFieldDidEndEditing is fired when the textfield resigns it's first responder status while textFieldShouldReturn is fired when the return button is pressed.

It *sounds* like your textfield is never resigning as firstResponder.  You can check it pretty easily by putting some debug output (as suggested in the comments) and just navigating out of the textfield with a touch - eg start typing then just touch outside of the field to force it to resign firstResponder.

Not sure if that helps a lot, but it sounds like a strange case you are hitting.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  Take a look at the code that I added to the initial question.  testFieldShouldReturn: does call resignFirstResponder, and I've confirmed that the resignation line of code executes via the debugger.

Does textFieldDidEndEditing: get called as part of resignFirstResponder's execution, or does it occur *after* resignFirstResponder completes execution?

Finally, in case it matters, I'm still running in the simulator rather than the actual device.  I don't have the magic keys yet.

Comment: More info on this...I whipped out HelloWorld demo app--has a textfield, button, and label: type text into field, hit button, label updates.  I modified the nib so that the label sends an "Editing Did End" event to the same object and action that the button uses.  And it worked.  So, I went back to my app described above and did the same thing...and it didn't work.  There must be something subtly different, but so far I haven't spotted it.

Comment: One other thing I'd check is that the method signature for textFieldDidEndEditing *exactly* matches the signature from the api docs, it looks right to me but if there is any error in that the delegate method won't ever be called.  You can actually copy the signature directly out of the API docs to be sure.

Comment: Excellent advice Paul.  Unfortunately, I already tried that to no avail.  See my followup answer to be added soon.

Answer (score 4):

If you adopted *UITextFieldDelegate* protocol in your view controller, then write the following line of code in *viewDidLoad* method to activate the methods of above protocol to your corresponding textFields:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //other stuff
    yourTextField.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up wiring up editingChanged to record every single change to a text field rather than figuring out how to cover all the corner cases with the remaining callbacks.

Very "efficient" due to the android-like "usability" of the textFieldDidEndEditing (sarcasm).

Answer (score 1):

In my case `textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` wasn't called because of instead this there was implemented `textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField reason:(UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason)reason`. For some reason on iOS 13.4 it wasn't called.

I fixed it just removing `reason ...`.

The question why the `reason` callback stopped working is still open, but the short one works correctly.

[image]

Comment: Because If you are using method with reason, Then it will not let the normal DidEndEditing get called.

Answer (score 0):

just a couple of Notes, expecially if you have ONLY 1 edit field:
call resignFirstController.

see below:

```
//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let s=textField.text ?? "0"
    let value = Double(s) ?? 0.0
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
   // Preferences.shared.ms = value
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("should return called.." )
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
  }
```

Comment: It makes no sense to call `resignFirstResponder` in `textFieldDidEndEditing`. `textFieldDidEndEditing` is only called  *after* the text field is no longer the first responder. Also, this is basically the code in the question so I'm not sure what this answers.

Comment: no. try removing.... without resigning You cannot be called in textFieldDidEndEditing. You will e called if OTHER becomes first, but in case You had e ONLY one edit, this is the way.

Answer (score -1):

Simple add delegate and use below code

TextField.delegate = self
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
self.calculateZmiles(amount: self.TextField.text ?? "")
}