# How do I get UI elements to play nice as peers (separate nibs) when contained in another nib?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitextfield

I have a nib (Nib #1) defining a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a `UITextField` in it. This nib's File's Owner is a generic `UIViewController` so I can instantiate in any VC.

I have another nib (Nib #2) that holds a `UIButton`, that is connected to an `IBAction` in File's Owner. This is a specific `UIViewController` instance, let's call it `FormViewController`.

Both of these nibs are connected to `FormViewController`.

Here is my problem.

I have a `UITableView` with two instances of Nib #1. When I click through the corresponding `UITextField` elements, the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods such as `textFieldDidEndEditing:` get triggered. HOWEVER, if I click the `UIButton` in Nib #2, the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods don't get called. **Why aren't they triggered?** Is it because those `UIView`s have different File's Owners? How do I get around this problem?

Possible related question: [why is textFieldDidEndEditing: not being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228298/why-is-textfielddidendediting-not-being-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textFieldDidEndEditing: method gets triggered when the UITextField resigns "firstResponder" status.

UITextField automatically resigns as firstResponder when you tap another object (such as another UITextField) that becomes the new firstResponder.

Since UIButton does not become firstResponder when tapped, you will need to call "resignFirstResponder" on your UITextField in order to trigger textFieldDidEndEditing:

An easy way to accomplish this if you don't know who the firstResponder is to call endEditing: on your view.

"Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status." -apple docs

Example:

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

  [self.view endEditing:YES];
  }

Comment: This is a very simple answer. Thanks. It turns out, this really doesn't have anything to do with peer nibs.